# SQL Server Report Server (SSRS) via WCF: HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'

Tags: .net-core, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, wcf-security

I have a .Net Core 3.1 application which is trying to connect to a SQL Server Report Server via WCF, in order to programmatically generate reports on demand.

But the program is not able to authenticate against the Report Server.

Here is the relevant program code:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10485760; //10MB limit

// Create the execution service SOAP Client
var rsExec = new ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient(
    binding,
    new EndpointAddress("http://my-ssrs/ReportServer")
);

// Setup access credentials.
var clientCredentials = new NetworkCredential(
    "MyReportServerUserName",
    "MyReportServerPassword",
    "."
);
if (rsExec.ClientCredentials != null)
{
    rsExec.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel =
        System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

    rsExec.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = clientCredentials;
}


// ************************************************
// Get following Exception when next line executes.
// ************************************************
await rsExec.LoadReportAsync(null, "/path-to/my-report", null);
```

When the last line ("rsExec.LoadReportAsync") is executed, I get the following exception:

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.
```

The Report Server is on the same Windows Domain.

After some research, I've tried changing the ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows but this generated a different exception, as follows:

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions about what I might try?

Comment: This link may help you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f458b52c-03d1-46c6-b502-8c8966035bae/the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client-authentication-scheme-ntlm-the-authentication-header?forum=sqlreportingservices

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Solved it by additionally setting the proxy credential type:

binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpProxyCredentialType.Ntlm;